# Need a program which print out every Symbol of the command line arguments and the fitting argument

Tags: java, iterator, set, command-line-arguments, hashset

my program should print out every symbol in the Set inclusive the fitting command line parameters . So I wrote this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Character> mySet = new HashSet<Character>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            for(int j = 0; j < args[i].length(); ++j) {
                mySet.add(args[i].charAt(j));
            }
        }
        Iterator<Character> iter = mySet.iterator(); 
        while (iter.hasNext()) { 
            Character s = iter.next(); 
            System.out.print("Zeichen: " + s + " - Kommadozeilenparamter:[");
            for(int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
                if(args[i].indexOf(s) > 0) {
                            System.out.print(" " + args[i]);
                }
                
            }
            System.out.print(" ]");
            System.out.println();
         }
```

That's not the best and smartest way to do this task...I'm a beginner ;(
When I do the input like : ab bca cd -> then I should get :
[Kommandozeilenparamter is German for command line parameters / Zeichen ist German for symbol]

```
Zeichen: a - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ ab bca ]
Zeichen: b - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ ab bca ]
Zeichen: c - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ bca cd ]
Zeichen: d - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ cd ]
```

but I got:

```
Zeichen: a - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ bca ]
Zeichen: b - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ ab ]
Zeichen: c - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ bca ]
Zeichen: d - Kommadozeilenparamter:[ cd ]
```

Comment: Indices of a string are zero based. Even though `0` is also a valid value you are only checking for indexes greater than `0`. Change in your if condition `if(args[i].indexOf(s) > 0)` to `if(args[i].indexOf(s) >= 0)`